# Jquery - checking to see if a box is checked

Tags: jquery

I have a list of boxes on a page and im trying to see if the check box in each elemenent is checked.

I did "inspect" on the box, and have been checking/unchecking the box looking for changes in the DOM. The only difference I can see is that the `::after` appears/disappears if a box is checked.

Before the box is checked:

```
<div class="member-select fit-additional-content">
    <input type="checkbox" class="select-member small-input" id="select-9804342" value="9804342" dir="ltr">
    <label data-tracking-control-name="selectProfileCheckbox" for="select-9804342">
         ::before
         <span class="hide-a11y">Select Erwin Tam</span>
    </label>
</div>
```

After the box is checked:

```
<div class="member-select fit-additional-content">
    <input type="checkbox" class="select-member small-input" id="select-9804342" value="9804342" dir="ltr">
    <label data-tracking-control-name="selectProfileCheckbox" for="select-9804342">
        ::before
        <span class="hide-a11y">Select Erwin Tam</span>
        ::after
    </label>
</div>
```

Am I missing something? This doesn't seem right. I would expect there to be some class name or element on the page to change to tell the DOM a box is checked.

Can I detect the existences of `::after` with a jquery selector? Where else could I possibly look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
$('#select-9804342').is(':checked')
```

to see if this specific checkbox is checked (instead of the id `select-9804342` you could also use a different selector). It returns `true` if it's checked, or `false` otherwise.

The existence/disappearing of `::after` is only related to CSS/styling. It has nothing to do with the actual state of the checkbox.

Comment: I figured about the ::after, didn't know about :checked! thank you